# how to stop event propagation inside <table>?

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js

I have mouseover and mouseout events attached to . The problem is these events are triggered when mouse hovers over  and  elements inside  even when I assign d3.event.stopPropagation and pointer-events..

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.divContainer{
    margin: 10em;
    background-color: darkorange;
    padding: 1em;
}
table{
background: steelblue;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="divContainer">
        <table>
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                    <td>
                    Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                    <td>
                    Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                    <td>
                    Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                    <td>
                    Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                    <td>
                    Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
            </tr>

    </table>
</div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>    


d3.select('table').on('mouseover',efunc1)

function efunc1(){
    alert("adf")
}

d3.select('table').on('mouseout',efunc)

function efunc(){
    alert("mouseout")
}


d3.select("tr").attr("pointer-events", "none")
d3.select("td").attr("pointer-events", "none")
// d3.select('table').on('mouseover',function(){d3.event.stopPropagation();})
d3.select('tr').on('mouseover',function(){d3.event.stopPropagation();})
// d3.select('td').on('mouseover',function(){alert("inside td")})


// d3.select('table').on('mouseout',function(){d3.event.stopPropagation();})
d3.select('tr').on('mouseout',function(){d3.event.stopPropagation();})
// d3.select('td').on('mouseout',function(){d3.event.stopPropagation();})

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're wanting to do to the `<tr>` and `<td>` elements, you're only doing to one of them with `.select`, rather I think you need `.selectAll`

Also, pointer-events is a css property so should be set with `.style` not `.attr` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

See if this does what you want (events triggering only when entering/leaving the table) -  you may not need the `.stopPropagation` selects

```
d3.selectAll("tr").style("pointer-events", "none")
d3.selectAll("td").style("pointer-events", "none")
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that, but the event still fires after I change to selectAll....

Comment: Have you changed .attr to .style as well?